# Visual Studio WPF Designer does not use overwritten SystemColors

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, visual-studio-2017, visual-studio-designer

I am currently trying to overwrite the WPF system colors. From [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/e6118e71-2512-414f-a5a5-4b6f65bd4f75/wpf-xaml-how-to-override-systemcolors-for-whole-application?forum=wpf) I found out that this can be done by creating a new SolidColorBrush resource with for example the key `x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.WindowBrushKey}"` to change the Window's background color.

This already works however the Visual Studio WPF Designer does not show the new color as background of the Window.

Starting with a clean WPF App this is what my XAML code looks like for the MainWindow:

```
<Window x:Class="TestOverwriteSystemColor.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TestOverwriteSystemColor"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Window.Resources>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.WindowBrushKey}" Color="Orange" />
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

In the Visual Studio Designer this looks like this:

[image: Visual Studio WPF Designer View]

And that is the resulting application if I run it:

[image]

Also adding the `SolidColorBrush` Resource to the App.xaml resource does not change this. What am I missing that the newly defined SystemColor is also used in the Designer?

Comment: Not sure if blend will be able to help you with this.

Comment: I checked it in Blend and the visualization is the same as in the Visual Studio Designer (Background still white). Are there any tools in Blend I can use to further investigate this phenomena?

Comment: I've noticed that some colors, as `SystemColors.ControlTextBrushKey` are correctly applied to the XAML designer. It looks like this is a bug on the designer ignoring the value of `SystemColors.WindowBrushKey`.

Answer (score 0):

As Otiel mentioned this probably is a bug in Visual Studio, so I started a problem report at Microsoft. For now it is Under Consideration: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/633508/overwriting-resource-windowbrushkey-does-not-have.html